# Is $F_1$ a subfield of $K_f$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a subfield of $\mathbb C$ and let $f \in F[x]$. Let $K_f=$ the splitting field for $f$ over $F$. Suppose $F_1/F$ is a Galois extension of prime degree. Is $F_1$ a subfield of $K_f$?

FYI, I am attempting to prove a lemma to help me solve [Prove that if the Galois group of a polynomial $f$ is a nonabelian simple group, then the roots are not solvable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802645/prove-that-if-the-galois-group-of-a-polynomial-f-is-a-nonabelian-simple-group))

Comment: Just for the simplest case, $F=\Bbb Q$, there are (infinitely many) cyclic Galois extensions of every prime degree, but $K_f$ is one field extension of $F$, which can’t possibly contain all this multiplicity of extensions. I’m sure you must have been thinking of something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the givens, you shouldn't expect $f$ and $F_1$ to be related. For example, take:

- $F = \mathbb{Q}$
- $f = x$
- $F_1 = \mathbb{Q}(i)$

Then $K_f = \mathbb{Q}$, which not an overfield of $F_1$ (whether you ask the question abstractly or as subfields of $\mathbb{C}$).

If you want an example where $K_f$ is a nontriival extension, take $f = x^2 - 2$.

Comment: +1 Thank you for this simple counterexample. As a follow-up problem to this, you might be interested in checking out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802645/prove-that-if-the-galois-group-of-a-polynomial-f-is-a-nonabelian-simple-group. In this problem, (which has more initial assumptions), must $F_1 \subset K_f$? If not, how can the problem be solved?